# Angular material checkboxes filter are not filtering the mat table. No errors in the terminal and console

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have written the codes to the best of my ability, but the checkbox function is not filtering the table. These are the lines of codes on the ts file

```
displayColumns: string[] = ['createDate', 'createdBy', 'status', 'transactionNumber', 'transactionType', 'party', 'id'];

filterOptions(positionValue: string[], nameValue: string[]): ITransactionDetail[] { if ((!positionValue || positionValue.length === 0) && !nameValue) { return this.data; } const filtered = this.data.filter(periodicElement => { return ( (nameValue ? periodicElement.transactionType.toLowerCase().includes(nameValue.toString().toLowerCase()) : false) || (positionValue ? positionValue.includes(periodicElement.id + '') : false) ); }); return filtered; }

applyFilter(filterValue: string) { this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase(); this.dataSource.filter = filterValue; }


customFilterPredicate() { const myFilterPredicate = function(data: ITransactionDetail, filter: string): boolean { const searchString = JSON.parse(filter); return ( data.id .toString() .trim() .includes(searchString.position) && data.transactionType .toString() .trim() .toLowerCase() .includes(searchString.transactionType.toLowerCase()) ); }; return myFilterPredicate; }
```

The codes in the ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(){ this.positionFilter.valueChanges.subscribe(positionFilterValue => { this.dataSource.data = this.filterOptions(positionFilterValue, this.nameFilter.value); }); this.nameFilter.valueChanges.subscribe(nameFilterValue => { this.dataSource.data = this.filterOptions(this.positionFilter.value, nameFilterValue); }); }
```

These are the codes in the html

```
Create Date {{ position.createDate | json }} {{ element.createDate }}
```

They are displaying the values on the web page, but they are not filtering the table.

Comment: can you please format your code ? Kinda unreadable...

Comment: Before you update `this.dataSource` try setting it to empty array `this.dataSource = [];` and then assign the new value to it.

Comment: In ```customFilterPredicate``` you have used ```searchString.position```, but the ```displayColumns``` doesn't contain 'position', it contains 'id'.  And due to sufficient code present, I can only assume the scenario is happening because of ```id``` and ```position``` . Please verify the code..

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested Sai, it still didn't filter. Do I have to add an onSelection function to the logic